# .NET targetFramework="4.5" not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, .net-4.5

I'm developing a web app in .NET and it has target 4.5 (can't use 4.0 because some people used 4.5 only features). Right now I'm trying to upload the app into IIS but it shows me this error (It's in Spanish but I'll translate):

> [error message screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t35.0-12/10840103_10153403973843989_930502773_o.jpg?oh=347770d8432b8af54ee4df30642a8e98&oe=548807EB&__gda__=1418189306_0576120844d50cb6f5b20e717ced0802)
>
> Atributo 'targetFramework' no reconocido. Tenga en cuenta que en los nombres de atributo se distinguen mayúsculas y minúsculas.
>
> *Unrecognized attribute targetFramework. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive*

I'm pretty sure I have IIS with .NET framework installed, and I have searched a lot and found out that it seems not to exist v4.5 for IIS, but it still doesn't work.

[configuration screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t35.0-12/10860259_10153403974023989_1887456235_o.jpg?oh=ad1a3ac3f4692561cdc2f8ecd79e0d5d&oe=5487F66F&__gda__=1418136642_4c3886067f7c697fab7ddd1211416f03)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the last lines in the first screenshot, it seems your IIS application pool is using the .NET CLR 2.0.

You should double check which application pool your ASP.NET application is actually using, and change the application pool settings to use the .NET CLR 4.0

Comment: To add to Svein answer. Both .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 executes under the same CLR (4.0). A bit like 2.0 to 3.5 uses CLR 2.0 as well. So using the 4.0 pool (assuming 4.5 is installed on the machine) is the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: The problem was i did change the version in the app pool but i actually was creating a new one so the project where it really was, was only ready v2.0(dummy mistake havent sleep much these days finishing this project) also had to run aspnet_regiis.exe -i for 4.0 thanks